# Puppeteer Async .$eval throwing error outside try/catch

Tags: jquery, async-await, try-catch, puppeteer, eval

I'm trying to use Puppeteer to extract information from elements in a list, but can't handle simple error being thrown in `try`/`catch` or `.catch()`.

- Some `item` elements don’t have `grandchild3`
- When trying to handle these exceptions with `try`/`catch` or `.catch()`, the code block passes, then (outside `try`/`catch` and `.catch()`) `value3` returns a `ReferenceError`, crashing the program.

HTML:

```html
<html>
<ul class=”list”>
    <li class="item">
        <div class="item_div">
            <div class=”item_info”>
                <h3 class=”grandchild1”>text</div>
                <div class=”grandchild2”>text</div>
                <div class=”grandchild3”>text</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</html>
```

Puppeteer code I'm having trouble with:

```js
const testElementDetailList = await page.$$(".item")

for (let i = 0; i < testElementDetailList.length; i++) {
    const value1 = await testElementDetailList[i].$eval(".grandchild1", el => el.innerText)
    const value2 = await testElementDetailList[i].$eval(".grandchild2", el => el.innerText)
    var value3 = undefined 
    try {
       value3 = await testElementDetailList[i].$eval(".grandchild3", el => el.innerText)
    } catch (error) {
        // handle value3 being undefined in html
    }
    console.log(value1)
    console.log(value2)
    console.log(value3)
}
```

How can I catch errors when setting `value3`, and handle these like in a `try`/`catch` block?

Comment: Is this really your HTML? `<ul/>` is invalid syntax and there are illegal rich text quotes everywhere. Anyway, I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. The code you share should basically work, maybe remove `var` from in front of `value3 = await ...` because it's already defined outside the `try` block.

Comment: just an additional note: `page.$eval` is not part of jQuery, it is a method specific to puppeteer where `$` sign is being the chrome DevTools shorthand for `document.querySelector()` (and `$$` is for `document.queryselectorAll()`). I suggest editing the title and tags. but first of all to provide a more accurate HTML DOM segment as ggorlen suggested so the community can reproduce the issue and help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found the issue**

The referenceError seemed to be caused by declaring variable value3 before, then modifying it's value inside the try catch block, then calling it below in the console.log. Deleting the call inside the console.log solved the issue.

Before initially posting this question i read about async causing problems with try catch, and believed this to be the issue.